# Azure Storage UseDevelopmentStorage=true when using KeyVault

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-keyvault

I have configured my API to get the Azure Storage connection string from Azure KeyVault using Managed Identity.

Now the problem is that when I run the code locally in Visual Studio, it no longer uses the connection string from the appsettings.development.json which was    `"StorageAccount": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"`

Therefore I can't use the emulator when running locally.

I have created the following condition in my controller to work around this issue :

```
    public FileController(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            conn = this.configuration.GetConnectionString("StorageAccount");

        }
        else
        {
            conn = this.configuration["StorageConnectionString"];

        }
    }
```

Is this the proper way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In local, if your `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` set to `Development`, then it will read you local storage account like `UseDevelopmentStorage=true`.

When you publish to azure, it will use your webapp's MSI to get the connectionstring from key vault.

For more details, you could refer to the following code:

```cs
private IConfiguration _configuration;
private IWebHostEnvironment _env;

public WeatherForecastController(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
    _env = env;
}

if (_env.IsDevelopment())
{
    con = _configuration.GetSection("StorageAccount").Value;
}
else
{
    AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
    con = keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("https://xxxx.vault.azure.net/secrets/xxxx").GetAwaiter().GetResult().Value;

}
```

Comment: This is essentially what I did above. So you confirm there is no way around having the conditional check on IsDevelopment ?

Comment: Yes, you have to do like this.